# How to extract the this address using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to extract the this address using Selenium and Python

HTML:

```
<span class="mrehover dn" id="morehvr_add_cont0">
    <span class="blckarw"></span>
    <span class="cont_fl_addr">60-B, J D Alves Premises, Hill Road, Bandra West, Mumbai - 400050, Next to Bandra Medical Store</span>
</span>
```

Comment: <span class="mrehover dn" id="morehvr_add_cont0">
       <span class="blckarw"></span>
       <span class="cont_fl_addr">60-B, J D Alves Premises, Hill Road, Bandra West, Mumbai - 400050, Next to Bandra Medical Store</span>
      </span>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS selector `span.cont_fl_addr` if you dont like XPATH

Answer (score 0):

To print the address *60-B, J D Alves Premises, Hill Road, Bandra West, Mumbai - 400050, Next to Bandra Medical Store* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='cont_fl_addr']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.cont_fl_addr"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)